# overflow и высота блока в %

Tags: html, css

столкнулся с проблемой, в общем на сайте в body должен быть отключен скролл, а у левого блока он должен присутствовать, все работает, но только если высоту левого блока задавать в пикселях, если же задать height:100% или auto то скролл не появляется, как это можно решить? Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы блоку задаете высоту в процентах, он её вычисляет относительно родительского блока(с указанным позиционированием).

```css
.area {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 300px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="area">
        <div class="content">
            A
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```